Why can't this op-amp circuit output 0V with a single power supply?
I have this basic design. The input is from a signal generator (rectangular pulses 0V-6V 10Hz.)  The desired output is 12V pulse 10Hz.

I would like to avoid using -15VDC supply but with a single power supply the op-amp can't produce 0V. The lowest is around 4V. It can only do 0VDC with a dual power supply. I tried other op-amps in LTspice but the results are the same. Is my simulation wrong?
Single power supply:

Dual power supply:


No, the simulation is correct. Zero V at at the output with a single supply is impossible. A small current is flowing through the output transistor of the opamp to GND, the resistance of the output transistor could not be zero, therefore the output voltage could not be zero.

Hi
Use another opamp like AD820, unless there are some other specific requirements.

Does the low output have to be 0.000 V?  If not, what is an acceptable low output voltage?  Also, is a linear amplifier required, or would a 2-3 transistor pulse amplifier work in your application?

it needs  to have linear output eg voltage follower as input signal could have amplitude of 2V so output needs to be 4V.

I tried AD820 and it can go down to 0V at single power supply. what's the difference against AD4610?

The input range of the ADA4610 is the main problem here.
The ADA4610 is described in the data sheet as a: -
Low Noise, Precision, Rail-to-Rail Output, JFET Single/Dual/Quad Op Amp

But, it doesn't say that it's inputs can get to close to the rails in fact, you can't typically drive the inputs closer to either rail by 2.5 volts: -

The above extract is for +/- 5 volt rails but, the same limitation applies on anything up to +/- 15 volt rails. So, you either use a negative rail of at least 2.5 volts or find an op-amp that has the ability to work right down to the negative rail.

I tried AD820 and it can go down to 0V at single power supply. what's the difference against AD4610?

@ArielNarboada I don't understand your question. If we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
